# 3D flow charts / block diagrams?

Tags: graphics3d

In some cases I have flowcharts / block diagrams that are too busy, because they have lots of connections, so I have connection lines going over, under, and around other lines.

One solution to this would be to create a 3D diagram.

Is there a way I can generate such a diagram in Mathematica? What I need to do is to have colored, labeled blocks connected with (possibly labeled) pipes in 3D space.

Comment: `Graph3D` exists.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example with UML class diagrams using a package described in these posts:

- ["UML Diagrams Creation and Generation" (Community)](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/823206), and
- ["UML Diagrams Creation and Generation" (WordPress)](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2016/03/14/uml-diagrams-creation-and-generation-2/)

Load the package:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/\
MathematicaForPrediction/master/Misc/UMLDiagramGeneration.m"]
```

Make a 2D UML diagram:

```
UMLClassGraph[{Library \[DirectedEdge] Building, 
  Museum \[DirectedEdge] Building, 
  Member \[DirectedEdge] Person}, {}, {Library <-> Member, 
  Museum \[DirectedEdge] Member, Client \[DirectedEdge] Building, 
  Client \[DirectedEdge] Person}, {Library \[DirectedEdge] Book}, 
 "Abstract" -> {Building, Person}, "EntityColumn" -> False, 
 VertexLabelStyle -> "Text", ImageSize -> Large, 
 GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"]
```

[image]

Make a corresponding 3D UML diagram using the option specification `"GraphFunction" -> Graph3D`:

```
UMLClassGraph[{Library \[DirectedEdge] Building, 
  Museum \[DirectedEdge] Building, 
  Member \[DirectedEdge] Person}, {}, {Library <-> Member, 
  Museum \[DirectedEdge] Member, Client \[DirectedEdge] Building, 
  Client \[DirectedEdge] Person}, {Library \[DirectedEdge] Book}, 
 "Abstract" -> {Building, Person}, "EntityColumn" -> False, 
 VertexLabelStyle -> "Text", ImageSize -> Large, 
 GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "GraphFunction" -> Graph3D]
```

[image]

By removing `GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"` we get the non-intersecting 3D graph:

[image]

Comment: That is a pretty interesting approach I would not have thought of. I had originally envisioned using blocks with the label right on the block, but that would have the disadvantage that as the reader turned the model, the label would become less readable.

Comment: @TylerDurden I was not sure how the 2D tables are going to look in 3D, but `Graph3D` handles it nicely.